How do I make two test roots with the same package name?
I'm trying to implement the following structure in my module.  It's a gradle project.
./src/main/java/mypackage
./src/test/java/mypackage
./src/testfx/java/mypackage  --I want to add this!
I'd like all the test files to be in the same package as the source. We keep methods/variables package private to make testing easier. This is how it is in the existing test package.  If I don't mark the testfx directory as a test root then Intellij won't index it (yes I tried invalidating caches).  If I do mark it as a test root then Intellij wants the package name for my test files under testfx to be "java.mypackage".  I want it to be "mypackage".  Is there a way to do this?

Does this answer your question? Howto add another test source folder to Maven and compile it to a separate folder?

No, using gradle not maven and edited above to indicate as much.  The accepted solution is to add a testfx module, but I will still lose the advantage of the test being in the same package as the source correct?

Then you may want to do something like this (github.com).

This documentation may be helpful. Note the answer by Simon and the link provided by Turning85 show two different approaches. The former simply adds a root source directory for Java files to the existing test source set. In contrast, the latter creates an entirely new source set. Creating a new source set may be the better fit for your use case, especially with src/testfx/java being the desired root (that matches the src/<source-set-name>/java pattern).

You want to add a directory to your test source set. In your build file:
// Groovy DSL
java.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs('src/testfx/java')

// Kotlin DSL, shortening further per @Slaw comment
java.sourceSets.test { java.srcDirs("src/testfx/java") }


I believe the Kotlin DSL can be simplified to sourceSets.test { java.srcDirs("...") }.

Yes indeed. Nice one
